# Swift Firebase using an unspecified index

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have a chat app and my data is structured like so

```
chats : {
    chat12345 : {
        members : {
            user123 : true,
            user456 : true,
        }
    }
}

users : {
    user123 : {
        chats : {
            chat12345 : true
        }
    }
}
```

So when I want to grab a list of the user's chats, I simply use:

```
let ref = dbref.child("users").child("user123").child("chats")
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

    let chatRef = dbref.child("chats").child(snapshot.key)

        chatRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (chatSnapshot) in

            //I now have the chat object

        })
})
```

So you see above, that I am able to query each chat ID to get the chat object from Firebase successfully.

But I also need to observe changes to chats that I am a member of, for instance if the chat title, image, or other properties change.

So when I try the following:

```
let queryRef = chatRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "members/user123").queryEqual(toValue: true)

queryRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

})
```

This technically works, but the console outputs the following:

```
Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "members/user123" at /chats to your security rules for better performance.
```

How do either modify security rules or my query to observe changes to chats of which I am a member?

Here are my security rules right now:

```
"chats": {

    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "$chatId" : {
        "members": {
          ".indexOn": ".value"
        }
    }

 },
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not queryOrderedBy(/key/$variable) you need to structure  your data something like your variables stay at chatRef. Then you could use static indexes.